# Why isn't Django URL converter type working?

Tags: django

I am trying to write a unit test that will test a URLconf that follows Django's latest simplified URL routing syntax.  This syntax allows the captured value to include a converter type.  But what I've found is that the converter type doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the URLconf I want to test:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('club/<int:club_id>/', login_required(views.show_club), {'template': 'show_club.html'}, name='show-club'),
    ...
]
```

As you can see, I want to pass the club ID as an integer.  Now here is my test:

```
class TestURLs(TestCase):

    def test_show_club(self):
        path = reverse('show-club', kwargs={'club_id': 10})
        match = resolve(path)
        assert match.view_name == 'show-club'
        assert 'club_id' in match.kwargs
        assert match.kwargs['club_id'] == 10
```

When I run this test, I get an assertion error on the third assert:

```
File... in test_show_club assert match.kwargs['club_id'] == 10
AssertionError
```

If I insert a set_trace in my code and examine the match variable, I can see that the assertion is failing because the club_id key contains a string value of '10':

```
ResolverMatch(func=activities.views.show_club, args=(), kwargs={'club_id': '10', 'template': 'show_club.html'...})
```

If my converter type is `<int:club_id>`, shouldn't kwargs['club_id'] contain the integer value 10 instead of the string '10'?

I also inserted a set_trace in my code and then ran the code through that view.  When I did `print(type(club_id))` I also discovered that the value being passed in was a string.  Why is this integer converter type not working as advertised?  I'm using Django 2.0.13 and am on the path to upgrading to Django 2.2.

**Update**


I appreciate Daniel Roseman's reply.  If what he says is true, then the documentation appears to be incorrect.  The [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926762/why-isnt-django-url-converter-type-working) says,

> The new syntax supports type coercion of URL parameters. In the
>   example, the view will receive the year keyword argument as an integer
>   rather than as a string.

It's saying that the view will receive the argument as an integer, *not a string*.  The definition of "type coercion" on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) supports this:

> In computer science, type conversion, type casting, type
>   coercion, and type juggling are different ways of changing an
>   expression from one data type to another. An example would be the
>   conversion of an integer value into a floating point value or its
>   textual representation as a string, and vice versa.

Perhaps I'm just not reading it correctly.  But if the documentation is incorrect, then there's no point in my checking the kwarg's type in my test.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not what it does. The parameter will always be a string. The converter just ensures it is in the right format, ie that it only contains digits.

Edit because I think I see where the confusion is coming from. It's not a *type* converter, it's a *pattern* converter. It converts `<int:club_id>` to the equivalent regex, `(?P<club_id>\d+)`.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I always appreciate your answers.